# Regex find word occuring x times?

Tags: regex

Say I have the string:

> "foo bar foo x foo y bar foo"

I want to find words occurring three or more times, so "foo".

To find a word occuring more than once I have the regex

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\1)
```

I tried `(\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\1)){3,}`, but this returns no matches. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Regex is not the good choice in this case, since there's no "good" pattern you want to match. Why not using the language's features? It should be much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*(\b\w+\b)(?<!^.*\1.*\1)(?:(?:(?!\1).)*\1){3}(?:(?!\1).)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%28%5cb%5cw%2b%5cb%29%28%3f%3c!%5e.*%5c1.*%5c1%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c1%29.%29*%5c1%29%7b3%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c1%29.%29*%24&i=foo+bar+foo+x+foo+y+bar+foo)

**Explanation:**

- `^.*`: Match from the start.
- `(\b\w+\b)`: Match and capture a word in group #1
- `(?<!^.*\1.*\1)`: Lookbehind to assert no group #1 between the start and group #1

  - Currently, only the regex engine on .NET can evaluate [variable length lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind)
- `(?:(?:(?!\1).)*\1){3}`: Match something plus group #1 three times

  - `(?:(?!\1).)*`: Match anything except group#1
- `(?:(?!\1).)*$`: Match anything except group#1 to the end

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I'd limit it to between x and y matches?

Comment: change `{2}` to `{x,y}` where `x` and `y` are the lower and upper bounds respectively.

Comment: @roncook: See comment from Aaron. You can use: `(\b\w+\b)(?=(?:.*?\b\1\b){4,6})` for example.

Comment: @Aaron I tried this but it was still matching the word even when I went over the limit

Comment: I recognized the problem is not simple in regex. The correct solution cannot be evaluated on the most of the popular regex engine but the .NET one.